# A substitute for deprecated org.hibernate.query.Query.setParameters(Object[] os, Type type)

Tags: hibernate

Is there a substitute for `query.setParameters(Object[],Type)` method, the existing method is deprecated. Below is my code

```
Query query = dbSession.createQuery(sb.toString());
query.setParameters(objects.toArray(), types.toArray(new Type[0]));
pendingUsers = (ArrayList<User>) query.list();
```

Answer (score 3):

First check that you are using `org.hibernate.query.Query` instead of `org.hibernate.Query`
if you look at javadoc for 5.2 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/
you'll notice

> NOTE: Query is deprecated, and slated for removal in 6.0. For the time
>   being we leave all methods defined on Query rather than here because
>   it was previously the public API so we want to leave that unchanged in
>   5.x. For 6.0 we will move those methods here and then delete that class.

Also it's explained to just bind the values one at a time instead

> Deprecated. (since 5.2) Bind values individually

So just use any other setParameter() in that class in sequence

Comment: Not sure I get it. How are you supposed to do queries then?